# Append new element in row and save CSV [python]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, append

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
nom_ele_title,nom_ele_type,nom_ele_parent_id
Aspirateur,2,PLACARDS
COIN CUISINE,1,None
Plaques vitro,2,EQUIPEMENTS
Micro-ondes,2,EQUIPEMENTS
USTENSILES
Tabourets bar x 3
Horloge
Pack vaisselle
Pack verrerie
```

I would like that when the element has no "nom_ele_type" is "nom_ele_parent_id" add 1 for "nom_ele_type" and Yes for "nom_ele_parent_id" like this:

```
nom_ele_title,nom_ele_type,nom_ele_parent_id
Aspirateur,2,PLACARDS
COIN CUISINE,1,None
Plaques vitro,2,EQUIPEMENTS
Micro-ondes,2,EQUIPEMENTS
USTENSILES,1,Yes
Tabourets bar x 3,1,Yes
Horloge,1,Yes
Pack vaisselle,1,Yes
Pack verrerie,1,Yes
```

I thought it was possible to do it this way:

```
with open("./missed.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 1:
            row.append('1')
            row.append('Yes')
```

but the csv is not saved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save changed CSV data, you need to create a CSV Writer and expictly write the rows to it.

Try:

```
import csv

with open("missed.csv", "r") as fin, open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout) # added
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 1:
            row.append('1')
            row.append('Yes')
        writer.writerow(row) # added
```

Output:

```
nom_ele_title,nom_ele_type,nom_ele_parent_id
Aspirateur,2,PLACARDS
COIN CUISINE,1,None
Plaques vitro,2,EQUIPEMENTS
Micro-ondes,2,EQUIPEMENTS
USTENSILES,1,Yes
Tabourets bar x 3,1,Yes
Horloge,1,Yes
Pack vaisselle,1,Yes
Pack verrerie,1,Yes
```